# EF core: filter records matching any of the items in a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

(EDITED) I am experimenting with EF core with a document's table and a document triples table. Each document can include 0 or more (RDF) triples, represented by a predicate plus an object.

The corresponding EF entities are:

```
public sealed class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    // ...
    public IList<DocumentTriple> DocumentTriples { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public sealed class DocumentTriple
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string Predicate { get; set; }
    public string Object { get; set; }
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

Their SQL definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Document](
    [Id] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [CreatorId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Author] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    /* ... */
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentTriple](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentId] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Predicate] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Object] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DocumentTriple] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentTriple]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.DocumentTriple_dbo.Document_DocumentId] FOREIGN KEY([DocumentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Document] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentTriple] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.DocumentTriple_dbo.Document_DocumentId]
GO
```

Now, I'd want to apply a number of variable filters to the documents, using this pattern: I first create an `IQueryable` `documents` object, including the triples, and then add more and more filters like `documents = documents.Where(...)`.

One of these filters is a list of `Tuple`'s where 1=filter value for predicate and 2=null or filter value for object. I'd like to get only those documents with any of their triples matching at least 1 of the filter predicates or predicates/values pairs.

In SQL, I could do something like this:

```
select * from document
inner join documenttriple on documenttriple.documentid=document.id
where (documenttriple.[predicate]='somepredicate' and documenttriple.[object]='someobject')
or (documenttriple.[predicate]='somepredicate')
```

How could I do this in EF code? I tried:

```
documents = from d in documents
    join dt in db.DocumentTriples on d.Id equals dt.DocumentId
    where filter.Triples.Any(t => t.Item1 == dt.Predicate &&
        (t.Item2 == null || t.Item2 == dt.Object))
    select d;
```

but this does not seem to filter the triples.

**EDIT**

I try to explain myself better using more code samples. Here is my (shortened) code:

```
private IQueryable<Document> ApplyDocumentFilters(IQueryable<Document> documents, 
    DocumentFilter filter)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.CreatorId))
        documents = documents.Where(d => d.CreatorId == filter.CreatorId);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.CategoryId))
        documents = documents.Where(d => d.CategoryId == filter.CategoryId);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Title))
        documents = documents.Where(d => d.Title.Contains(filter.Title));
    // ...and so forth for all the filter properties...
    // here I want to filter only the documents which have at least 1 of their triples
    // matching any of the filter's triples. DOES NOT WORK
    if (filter.Triples.Count > 0)
    {
        documents = from d in documents
                    join dt in db.DocumentTriples on d.Id equals dt.DocumentId
                    where filter.Triples.Any(t => t.Item1 == dt.Predicate &&
                                                  (t.Item2 == null || t.Item2 == dt.Object))
                    select d;
    }
    return documents;
}

public PagedData<Document> GetDocuments(DocumentFilter filter)
{
    if (filter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter));
    using (CatalogContext db = new CatalogContext(_options))
    {
        IQueryable<Document> documents = db.Documents
                        .Include(d => d.DocumentTriples)
                        .AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
        documents = ApplyDocumentFilters(documents, filter);
        int total = documents.Count();
        documents = documents.OrderBy(d => d.Title).ThenBy(d => d.PublicationYear);
        return new PagedData<Document>(total,
            documents.Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize).Take(filter.PageSize).ToList());
    }
}
```

As you can see, I receive a filter object with all the filters I want to apply, and then build the IQueryable property by property. As for triples, I want to get all the documents having at least 1 triple which matches ANY of the filter's triples.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Query in Linq is

```
var i = from x in Db.Documents // SELECT * FROM Document
        join y in Db.DcumentTriple // JOIN DocumentTriples 
        on x.Id equals y.DocumentId // ON DocumentId = DocumentId
        where (y.Predicate.Equals("somepredicate") && // WHERE ( DocumentTriple.[Predicate] = 'somepredicate' &&
        y.Object.Equals("someobject")) || // DocumentTriple.[Object] = 'someobject') ||
        y.Predicate.Equals("somepredict") // DocumentTriple.[Predicate] = 'somepredicate'
        select new { x, y };
```

However you don't have to go a long way like that (I just translated the query, **That Query is a Bad Query**), it can be simply done as:

```
var i = Db.DocumenTriple.Where(x=> (x.Predicate.Equals("something") && x.Object.Equals("something")) || x.Predicate.Equals("something");
```

This will lazy load the `Db.Document` navigational property for you. If you wanna eager load it call `.Include(x=> x.Document)` at the end of it.

**Update**

As you mentioned in your comment, if I'm not mistaken, you have many `where` statements. In that case the following is possible:

```
public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TestEntity, Boolean>>> filters = new List<Expression<Func<TestEntity, Boolean>>>() { };
public IQueryable<TestEntity> filter(IQueryable<TestEntity> input, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TestEntity, Boolean>>> filters, int i) {
        if (i == 0)
            return input;
        return filter(input.Where(filters.ElementAt(i)), filters, i - 1);
}
```

**Please note that the order of filters in in this approach matters.** If you do not want this, you can use a `foreach` loop and `concat` the result to another list.

Comment: Thanks, my bad if I did not explain myself well, but I have an array of tuples representing a filter, and I am concatenating more and more where conditions on the same IQueryable. The SQL sample was intended to show the type of filtering, not the fact that in my scenario the code gets an array, and matching any of the tuples in it is enough to pass. In the end, I must have an IQueryable<Document> including their triples; I start with db.Documents.Include(d => d.DocumentTriples).AsNoTracking().AsQueryable(), add a number of filters to it, and end with sorting and paging it.

Comment: ok, I'm still confused about this, but if I have correctly understood the problem, you can do what I add in the updated answer.

Comment: I just edited the question by adding some concrete code. This should make my question clearer. Thank you